# gsutil cp error: cannot have start index greater than total size

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-storage, gsutil

I'm trying to download a lot of images from a Google Bucket that my employer's web host (not so) helpfully set up. I run the command gsutil cp -r gs://bucket-link-info/images/ . and the download starts fine. However, after a while, it stops with the error message "Service Exception: Transfer invalid cannot have start index greater than total size."

I have plenty of disk space left so that can't be the issue. I'm running the command prompt as an administrator (and ran the shell to get the prompt as an admin) who has read/write/execute rights on everything in the users/. I'm running Win7 Professional.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for this question - this is a [bug in gsutil 4.15](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/gsutil/issues/310) and it will be fixed for gsutil 4.16.

Until that's released, you can use a prerelease version:

Standalone installs:
`gsutil update gs://prerelease/gsutil_4.16pre_oauth2.tar.gz`

Cloud SDK installs:

```
gcloud components repositories add https://storage.googleapis.com/prerelease/cloudsdk-prerelease-components/gsutil_4.16pre_gcoauth2/components-2.json
gcloud components update
```